# MySQL conditional many to many

Tags: mysql

For the sake of this question I have created a very basic example of what I'd like to achieve (also trying to achieve this in Doctrine, but I'll settle for getting it working in mySQL first).

I have three tables `products`, `orderItems` and `orders`.

The `products` table has an `active` flag and the `orderItems` table is a simple many-to-many relationship between `products` and `orders`.

The application I'm building needs to only allow:

- new orders to only allow active products
- existing orders to use active products and or any inactive products currently within the order

I'd like to pull all of this out in a single query. New orders are easy enough...

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = true
```

Getting all of the inactive products for an order...

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orderItems i ON i.productId = p.productId
WHERE i.orderId = 123 and p.active = false
```

I kind of need to combine these two queries, so I retrieve all of the inactive products from the `products` table which are active and/or exist in the orderItems table and are inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select all products that are active or inactive products that have an entry in the `orderItems` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderItems i ON i.productId = p.productId
WHERE active = true OR
      (p.active = false AND i.productId is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the UNION operator will let you combine the two queries:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p WHERE p.active = true
UNION
SELECT p.* FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orderItems i ON i.productId = p.productId
WHERE i.orderId = 123 AND p.active = false
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about UNION, having one of those days :)